# How to get the item name and not its address when requesting with a "condition event" from a Simpy-Store

Tags: python, simulation, yield, simpy

A Simpy-Store is filled with elements {0}...{9}

```
car_Fleet = simpy.Store(env, capacity=10)
i = 0
for i in range(10):
    car_Fleet.put({i})
    i += 1
```

When requesting an item from that store

```
    car_id = yield car_Fleet.get()
    print(car_id)
```

the print statement returns the "value" of the Simpy-Store item, for example {4}

But when using a simpy condition event

```
with car_Fleet.get() as req:
    patience = 2
    results = yield req | env.timeout(patience)

    wait = env.now - arrive

    if req in results:
        .....
        print(req)
        .....

    else:
        # We quit
        ...
```

The `print(req)` (also `print(req.value)` ) statement returns "`<StoreGet() object at 0x7f8e2681da50>`" and not the value of the requested item as in the code above.
Also `print(results)` returns:  `<ConditionValue {<StoreGet() object at 0x7fe1c37f4b80>: <StoreGet() object at 0x7fe1c37f41f0>}>`

How can one access the value instead of the address of the item requested from the store?

Edit: Michaels comment solved the problem. The `results` variable can be accessed as follows. By using `results[req]` one can retrieve the name of the requested item. When returning an Item to the store it's also important to pass `results[req]` with `carFleet.put` .

Comment: The goal is to have multiple processes requesting a "car" from the "car-fleet". Processes should wait until a car becomes available, or if it takes too long, abort their request. I need the name "{1}" of the car for further logging purposes.  To my understanding i need the yield statement in order to allow a process to wait for a car to return as long the patience is not triggered.

Comment: your results var is a ordered dictionary. conditional events can return more then one event.  Your store.get and timeout can fire at the same time.  results will have a entry for every event fired.  try iterating over the dict and printing each dict entry.

Comment: instead of print(req), try print(results[req])